# Symfony 3 Associate Entity A with Entity B

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to figure out, what I believe to be a very common usecase, but can't quite find the right pointers.

Case:

I have a **product** entity and a **review** entity.
When rendering the product in the UI, I include a form underneath that visitors can use to write a small review about that product.

Obviously, when submitting the review, I need the product (object or Id) so I can associate the review with the product it was written for.

My first idea was to use a hidden input field in the form for this.
Symfony (3) throws me an error that it expects a fully hydrated product entity, instead of just an Id.

When googling around, I found that the symfony docs speak about Data Transformers here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).
Which IMHO feels like a huge overkill over such an easy task at hand.

Continuing my search, it appears that I am not alone as apparently many issues have been filed on the github repo for symfony itself:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8293

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6602

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15053

Finally there is even a repo that I found that seems to provide a solution on its own here:
https://github.com/Gregwar/FormBundle

Before taking on board this last repo's dependencies, I wanted to check here if anyone could advice if (and how) they solved this issue in the past.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to make this easy for you. Let's assume you have a controller and the method you're using is called "view". What you're going to want to do is have the form submit to a different method in your controller, lets call it "comment". So for the data transformation you'd declare the comment method like so:

```
/**
* @Route( "/comment/{id}", name="product_comment" )
*/
public function commentAction( Request $request, Product $product )
{
    ....other code goes here.
}
```

So the action of your form needs to be to the comment method and pass along the id of the product. Do this by modifying your form attributes and setting the action to the comment path and passing along the id of the product to the path. Symfony will be able to type-hint your Product entity using the route I showed you and translate it based on the Product type that is an argument for your method. Make sure to include the proper "use" statement at the top of your controller for your Product entity.

Comment: Of course! When looking at something for too long, you can just miss the obvious.
Many thanks!